# Count onlinetime and calculate coins

Tags: php, session

I've try to set the onlinetime and coins when user is signed in.

The user has to get 1 coins per. hour their online, i have calculated the onlinetime in seconds, but how can i make the correct count for coins?

Maybe it has to update every 35 second with the count for coins?

```
<?php
session_start();

// Set the session if not set.
if ( !isset ( $_SESSION['startOnlineTime'])):
    $_SESSION['startOnlineTime'] = time();
endif;


$secondsOnline = (time() - $_SESSION['startOnlineTime']);
?>
```

I've tried something like (without luck):'

```
<?php
    //if updates every 35 secs, then i calculate it like: 1 (per hour) / 35 (seconds) - 1/35? correct?
    $prHour = (Double) 0.028571428571429; 
    $SQL = "UPDATE users SET coins=coins+0.15 WHERE id = '@session_id()'";
    mysql_query($SQL) or die ( mysql_error() );
?>
```

But doesn't seem to be correct. What can i do?

Comment: When do you want to calculate this amount of time? At the end of a session, or periodically, ... ?

Comment: Periodically - every 35 seconds.

Comment: I don't even see where $prHour or $secondsOnline are being used

Answer (score 0):

This maybe one solution for your problem. Create a separate php file call `counter.php` with the content as follow. This file will be call periodically, in this example, hourly.

**counter.php**

```php
<?php
if(session_id() == '') {
    sesstion_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])
         return;
         // I use 'userid' to save the user info, you can use others like ip, session_id, ...

    // verify that this file is called hourly
    $t = time();
    if (isset($_SESSION['lastcheck']) && $t - $_SESSION['lastcheck'] < 3550)
         return;
         // if this script is call in the previous 1 hour (3600s), ignore this call.

    $_SESSION['lastcheck'] = time();
    /* update your database here, increment 1 coin in this user record */

}
?>
```

In **every** page that you want to charge your user, use JavaScrip to call the `counter.php` hourly. This example use jQuery library to help:

```js
 function charge() {
      var waitingTimes = 3600; //1 hours
      $.get("absolute/url/to/counter.php");
      setInterval(charge,waitingTimes)
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
      charge();          
 });
```

Comment: Not good. The users change the page after 2 seconds and it reset the counter, no thanks.

Comment: You can set how frequently the `counter.php` is called. The counter will not reset if it is called from the same session.